# Backbone Collection Initialization in View

Tags: backbone.js, collections, backbone-views

I'm having a hard time initializing a simple view with a collection that I'm pulling from an API. Everything I try returns an empty array when I try to return the collection from within the view.

```
app.models.Employee = Backbone.Model.extend({

});

app.collections.Employees = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    Model: app.models.Employee,
    url: "http://api.sample.com",

    initialize: function(){
        this.fetch();
    },

    parse: function(response){
        console.log(response)
    },

});

app.views.Container = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('.container'), 

    initialize: function(){
        this.collection = new app.collections.Employees();
        console.log(this.collection)
        var that = this;
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function(){
                that.render();
            }
        });
    },

    render: function(){
        console.log(this.collection) //returns no models
    }
});
```

Comment: So... it looks like you might have blocked the parsing of the data by putting that console.log in parse?   Try removing that completely unnecessary override parse method?

Comment: And you do realize you're calling fetch twice, right?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) correctly:

```
parse: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    return response;
} //`,` - remove it at last item in object
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 problems with your code

- You are using `parse` incorrectly. Per the specifications

> The function is passed the raw response object, and should **return the**
>   **array of model attributes** to be added to the collection

so yes, as @Sergey suggested

```
parse: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    return response;
}
```

or better, just remove your `parse` function, don't override it.

- You are calling your `fetch` function twice.

First time at this line

```
this.collection = new app.collections.Employees();
```

which eventually calls this function

```
initialize: function(){
        this.fetch();
    },
```

Second time is inside your initialize function in the View.

3) You break `render`

Again, same thing as your `parse`. You are supposed to

> renders the view template from model data, and updates this.el with
>   the new HTML

Something like this

```
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
    return this;
  }
```